# I am using mdbreact npm for react data tables with next.js what i want to add fa fa icon with the heading but i am unable to do it

Tags: reactjs, mdbreact

I am using mdbreact npm for data tables with next.js and i want to add fa fa sort icon with heading but it is not working below is my code and i already i tried it with CSS :-

```
// This is how i import mdbreact after installation :- 
import { MDBDataTable, MDBBtn, MDBTable, MDBTableBody, MDBTableHead } from 'mdbreact';

// These Are The Heading Of The Table :-
const columns = 
[
{ label: 'Customer Tag' + <i class="fa fa-sort" aria-hidden="true"></i>, field: 'Customer_Tag', sort: 'asc', width: 150 },
{ label: 'Discount Type', field: 'Discount_Type', sort: 'asc', width: 270 },
{ label: 'Discount Condition', field: 'Discount_Condition', sort: 'asc', width: 200 },
{ label: 'Enable/Disable', field: 'status', sort: 'disabled', width: 100 },
{ label: 'Action', field: 'action', sort: 'disabled', width: 100 },
];
```

// And This is My MDBreact Table
return(
    
)

Answer (score 2):

The value of label is supposed to be a string, so I suspect that's why it doesn't work. Docs here: https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/react/tables/datatables/

You will not be able to use the font awesome class names because you can't put an element in the label.

I don't have a good solution but here's two options:

I used react-table for my data tables and was able to do what you're attempting. Consider switching to react-table.

Don't use font awesome in this instance, try finding a html entity that means the same thing, such as something from this list: https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref

Comment: Not Working For Me Sir

Comment: Can you tell me how the original is 'not working' please? Are you getting a build error, a console error, is it just not displaying? Any error messages would be helpful.

Comment: while using this code i am getting below error :-    
                                                                             ./pages/component/dataTables.js
SyntaxError: C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\wholesaleapp\pages\component\dataTables.js: Unexpected token (73:34)
  72 |     const columns = [
> 73 |   { label: {'Customer Tag ' + <i className="fa fa-sort"></i>}, field: 'Customer_Tag', sort: 'asc', width: 150 },
     |                                   ^

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Yes, as per the documentation the label must be a string. Your error message shows me that it is enforced. No elements allowed. I'll update the answer with another suggestion.

Comment: Your help will be good for me. i also tried this :- const columns = [
        { label: <span>Customer Tag <i className="fa fa-sort" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>, field: 'Customer_Tag', sort: 'asc', width: 150 },
        { label: 'Discount Type', field: 'Discount_Type', sort: 'asc', width: 270 },
        { label: 'Discount Condition', field: 'Discount_Condition', sort: 'asc', width: 200 },
        { label: 'Enable/Disable', field: 'status', sort: 'disabled', width: 100 },
        { label: 'Action', field: 'action', sort: 'disabled', width: 100 },
    ];

Comment: Like This :- { label: <span>Discount Type &#x021F5;</span>, field: 'Discount_Type', sort: 'asc', width: 270 }

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with the entity, here is my code :-

const columns = 
[
 { label: Customer Tag ⇵, field: 'Customer_Tag', sort: 'asc', width: 270, attributes: {className :"fas fa-sort"} },
 { label: Discount Type ⇵, field: 'Discount_Type', sort: 'asc', width: 270 },
 { label: Discount Condition ⇵, field: 'Discount_Condition', sort: 'asc', width: 200 },
 { label: 'Enable/Disable', field: 'status', sort: 'disabled', width: 100 },
 { label: 'Action', field: 'action', sort: 'disabled', width: 100 },

];

Answer (score 0):

please include the below link

```
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css';
import 'bootstrap-css-only/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'mdbreact/dist/css/mdb.css';
```